# Fastest way to search two models connected via join table in rails given large data set

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a user model and a cd model connected through a join table 'cds_users'. I'm trying to return a hash of users plus each cd they have in common with the original user.

```
@user.users_with_similar_cds(1,4,5)
# => {:bob => [4], :tim => [1,5]}
```

Is there a better/faster way of doing this without looping so much?  Maybe a more direct way?

```
def users_with_similar_cds(*args)
  similar_users = {}
  Cd.find(:all, :conditions => ["cds.id IN (?)", args]).each do |cd|
    cd.users.find(:all, :conditions => ["users.id != ?", self.id]).each do |user|
      if similar_users[user.name]
        similar_users[user.name] << cd.id
      else
        similar_users[user.name] = [cd.id]
      end
    end
  end
  similar_users
end
```

[addition]

Taking the join model idea, I could do something like this.  I'll call the model 'joined'.

```
def users_with_similar_cds(*args)
  similar_users = {}
  Joined.find(:all, :conditions => ["user_id != ? AND cd_id IN (?)", self.id, args]).each do |joined|
    if similar_users[joined.user_id]
      similar_users[joined.user_id] << cd_id
    else
      similar_users[joined.user_id] = [cd_id]
    end
  end
  similar_users
end
```

Would this be the fastest way on large data sets?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `find_by_sql` on the Users model, and Active Record will dynamically add methods for any extra fields returned by the query.  For example:

```
similar_cds = Hash.new
peeps = Users.find_by_sql("SELECT Users.*, group_concat(Cds_Users.cd_id) as cd_ids FROM Users, Cds_Users GROUP BY Users.id")
peeps.each { |p| similar_cds[p.name] = p.cd_ids.split(',') }
```

I haven't tested this code, and this particular query will only work if your database supports `group_concat` (eg, MySQL, recent versions of Oracle, etc), but you should be able to do something similar with whatever database you use.

Comment: In my tests, this hasn't been faster.  Maybe on larger data sets it would be.

Comment: Hrm.  It seems likely that it would be - in the original code, you do one query to get the cds and then another query for each user found.  The find_by_sql variant does the whole shebang in one query, though it is a join with a group_concat.  If your dataset is small, the fact that single-table queries are faster than joins might even things out, but once you get a lot of similar users, the overhead of all those queries will probably bog you down.  You might also check to make sure you have indexes on all the foo_id columns.

Answer (score 0):

Yap, you can, with only 2 selects:

Make a join table model named CdUser (use has_many.. through)

```
# first select
cd_users = CdUser.find(:all, :conditions => ["cd_id IN (?)", args])
cd_users_by_cd_id = cd_users.group_by{|cd_user| cd_user.cd_id }

users_ids = cd_users.collect{|cd_user| cd_user.user_id }.uniq
#second select
users_by_id = User.find_all_by_id(users_ids).group_by{|user| user.id}

cd_users_by_cd_id.each{|cd_id, cd_user_hash| 
  result_hash[:cd_id] = cd_users_hash.collect{|cd_user| users_by_id[cd_user.user_id]}
}
```

This is just an ideea, haven't tested :)

FYI: http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many